# RStudio Viewer Pane not working?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have been trying to learn R to work on some network analysis.  I found the networkD3 package and ran their example code (below) to get acquainted.  It would switch to the "Viewer" tab on the right side of the console, but it would appear blank.  If I used the "Export -> Save As Web Page..." then I could open that saved html document in my browser and see what I expected to see.

I've tried a couple other things I think would open in that Viewer pane but it launches a tab in my browser.  I've even tried the rstudio::viewer("document.html") approach and it still goes to my browser.  Any ideas?

```
# Create fake data
src <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D")
target <- c("B", "C", "D", "J", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I")
networkData <- data.frame(src, target)

# Plot
simpleNetwork(networkData)
```

Comment: See here: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/202133558-Extending-RStudio-with-the-Viewer-Pane. There are instructions there

Comment: That's great for showing you how to use it, but in my case it isn't working.  That was my starting point but I'm starting to think something is behaving correctly on my system.

Answer (score 6):

It appears that in order for the internal viewer to work, your source documents **must** actually reside in "*the session temporary directory*" - as stated in the [support document](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/202133558-Extending-RStudio-with-the-Viewer-Pane). Thus - assuming you have a file `test.html` in your home directory - the following will open the file in your default browser ...

```
myViewer <- getOption("viewer")
myViewer("~/test.html")
```

... but to open it in the internal viewer pane you need this:

```
file.copy("~/test.html", file.path(tempdir(), "test.html"))
myViewer(file.path(tempdir(), "test.html"))
```

This also works with `.jpg` but not with `.pdf` (`.pdf`'s open in your default pdf viewer.) Incidentally, `file.show()` has related functionality: it will open `.html` and .jpg files in the edit pane - but not `.pdf` either.

Comment: So does the package need to add code to move the file into the temporary directory?  Why does it open a tab in the viewer pane but not actually display the content?  Thanks!