# Rstudio Viewer not working

Tags: r, rstudio

i am unable to view any javascript driven plots in my Rstudio viewer. I didn't have this problem 2 days before. I am experiencing this just in these 2 days. I thought updating Rstudio will work but that didn't happen.

As i run a code like this:

```
plotly(dataset, x = height, type = "histogram")
```

The R viewer gets the attention but it doesn't show anything and it is plain white.

Please help me.

[RStudio Viewer Pane not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732232/rstudio-viewer-pane-not-working) this question, too, didn't help.

I am stuck with this from two days and unable to do any further anyalysis.

Please can anyone help me.

for a screenshot of my problem please look here.https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000830228-Unable-to-view-plots-in-Rstudio-viewer