# Rstudio viewer not working - Mac OS

Tags: javascript, r, macos, rstudio

My RStudio viewer does not show any of java script plots and I could not find any solution from the previously asked questions below:
[Question one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42129051/rstudio-viewer-not-working) and [Question two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732232/rstudio-viewer-pane-not-working). But I can view `R Markdwown` documents.

My session details are as below:

> R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
>   Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
>   Running under: OS X El Capitan 10.11.4

Sample reproducible code is:

```
library(ggvis) 
mtcars %>% ggvis(~ wt,~ mpg) %>% layer_points()
```

Comment: It works fine for me in R 3.3.2 (as long as I remove the backquotes).

Comment: @user2554330 It doesn't  work for me, the viewer pane changes to plain white but blank, i have to go to Export->Save as web page to view my plot in browser and i wish to view it directly in viewer pane.

Comment: If you right click and "Inspect Element", you'll go into a debugger.  If you're lucky, you'll see informative error messages in the "Console" tab.  PS I removed the backquotes from your sample code.

Comment: No errors under the console tab, it's clean