# what is the r version of the release of getOption("viewer")

Tags: r, compiler-errors

I'm creating an r package and when I try to check it I have only one error saying that they can't find the function getOption("viewer") when it runs the examples. However when i try to run the examples manually it works and the function is acknowledged. That's why I'm just wondering if there could be a version problem in the building of the package since I specified it to be at 3.4.0.

Comment: Is the typo (missing "n") in the error message or only in your question?

Comment: Isn't the viewer RStudio specific?

Comment: @AEF Yes, `getOption("viewer")` returns `NULL` in Rgui.

Comment: Sorry Roland I don't understand your first question what's "missing "n" " ?

Comment: @neotis You have written "getOptio()" instead of "getOptioN()" in your question. Roland asked if this is already the cause of the error or just a typo in your question here.

Comment: Yep sorry I edited it, in my code this was correct, it looks like it's just in the check that it doesn't work

Comment: Can you tell us whether you're using RStudio or some other interface?  It looks like RStudio has had this at least since 2016 ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732232/rstudio-viewer-pane-not-working

Comment: My guess would be that it works in R Studio, but when you build/check your package its just R and the viewer is therefore not available.

Comment: It's rstudio, I installed the latest version and it still return this error.